# SOQL "no-op" WHERE clause

Tags: soql

Is there anything I can do in SOQL to achieve the same as WHERE 1=1 in regular SQL engines? I've tried that, and WHERE TRUE=TRUE, but it's rejected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All filters are in the form of "field operator value", so the closest approximation would be something like `WHERE Id <> NULL`, which should be true for most, if not all, objects.

Comment: We use this sometimes. It is, of course, going to mean a full table scan - indexing won't apply - but then if you are asking for all records, the table needs to be lightly populated anyway!

Comment: I am not sure I understand but in case I want to get all records why are we putting filter in first place?

Answer (score 1):

You could also do (for most objects)

```
WHERE CreatedDate < TOMORROW   returns all objects

WHERE CreatedDate > TOMORROW  returns no objects
```

Comment: I think you meant `WHERE CreatedDate < TOMORROW`, or alternatively, `WHERE CreatedDate != NULL`, though I agree overall that CreatedDate is probably a safe bet.

Comment: right-o; i misinterpreted the question as wanting the SOQL to fetch nothing